# SQL Stored Procedure Question

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having an issue trying to set variable in SQL in a stored procedure. I'm checking to see if a record is set to active, and the idea is to set it to inactive or vice versa.

Admittedly I'm not the best with SQL and have tried CASE statements along with my example, but nothings working...

Could someone show me what I'm missing???

Thanks!!!

```
 ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAlterStatus]
 @CID as int,
 @Active varchar(10)
 AS

select @Active = Active  from Course where
CID = @CID;

 if @Active='0' set @Active = '1';
 if @Active='1' set @Active = '0';


UPDATE Course
SET Active = @Active WHERE  CourseID = @CourseID
```

Comment: What dialect of SQL and what Server (MySQL, PostGreSQL, Oracle, SQLServer, etc)?

Comment: @ircmaxell he has it tagged [sql-server]

Comment: Obvious flag: your update references @CourseID while the param is @CID.

Also, are you certain that the return from the select is always '1' or '0' exactly?  You don't have any catch/case for any other values or paddings, and it'll silently update the row to its same value in those cases.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: I don't see that tag, just "sql" and "stored-procedures".

Comment: @rockinthesixstring That tag was edited in by Vinko after I made my comment (Before it just said "SQL", which is all @wali said)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do but does this work better:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAlterStatus] 
    (
     @CID int,
     @Active varchar(10)
     )
AS

SET @Active = (select Active  from Course where CID = @CID)

if @Active= '0' 
     BEGIN
     set @Active = '1';
     END
ELSE IF @Active= '1'
     BEGIN
     set @Active = '0';
     END

UPDATE Course
SET Active = @Active 
WHERE  CourseID = @CID
```

Comment: And then if it is possible to get something other than a 1 or 0 for active than but another case in there

Comment: Thanks to All, I apologize for being so vague with my question but I was pulling my hair a bit with frustration and running short on time...


Thanks to All!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why everyone is selecting AND updating - you can do this all in one operation:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAlterStatus] 
    @CID as int
AS 
    UPDATE Course 
    SET Active = CASE WHEN Active = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
    WHERE CourseID = @CID
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem:

```
if @Active='0' set @Active = '1';
if @Active='1' set @Active = '0';
```

These two statements execute one after another: so @Active always ends up being '0'.

Try something like this:

```
if @Active='0' set @Active = '1';
else set @Active = '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, maybe you have to rename the CID / CourseID. I think it should be the same field.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAlterStatus]
 @CID as int,
 @Active varchar(10)
 AS

select @Active = CASE Active WHEN '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Act from Course where
CID = @CID;

UPDATE Course
SET Active = @Active WHERE  CID = @CID
```

Comment: Thanks, edited. Dont know exactly, but it could be that you have to use the 'AS Act' to work. I remember an error using the case without an 'AS'.